# Quiver command not plotting the correct direction when setting angles as an array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the B vector in x and z plane. When I plot using quiver(x,z,u,v,angles='xy') where u and v are bx and bz components respectively. Though I am able to reproduce most of the plots, a small portion of the plot is not matching. Also in angles when I give the angle as an array of direction angles calculated as inverse tan bz/bx I am unable to get the correct solution. The angels calculated has been converted to degrees.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bx = [0.847718, 1.10198, 3.057813, 2.506806, 3.393603, 3.077797,
      2.146959, 0.819338, 0.927246, 0.744022]
bz = [5.795546, 6.50484, 4.179589, 4.434657, 4.450034, 4.771026,
      5.765941, 3.333912, 6.132857, 5.899621]
x_pos = [-4.0990367, -3.9878302, -3.8611758, -3.7163513, -3.55016, -3.3591635,
         -3.1397316, -2.8887184, -2.6041164, -2.2858455]
z_pos = [-1.7718704, -1.382828, -0.98846114, -0.5894755, -0.18716145, 0.21637209,
         0.61796373, 1.0132061, 1.3965136, 1.7616254]
b_angles1 = []
for i in range(len(bx)):
   b_angles1.append(np.arctan(bz[i] / bx[i]))
   b_deg_xz = np.degrees(b_angles1)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.quiver(x_pos, z_pos, bx, bz, angles='xy', color='red')
axs.quiver(x_pos, z_pos, bx, bz, angles=b_deg_xz, color='blue')
axs.set_ylim(-2, 2)
axs.set_xlim(1, -5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite an interesting problem.

The red arrows are plotted with `angles='xy'`, which ([according to the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html)) means that the red arrows point from `(x_pos, z_pos)` to `(x_pos + bx, z_pos + bz)`. This is in data coordinates.

The blue arrows are plotted with angles given by an array of angles `angles=b_deg_xz`. In that case, the arrows are plotted with angles going clockwise from the horizontal axis. This is, for lack of a better phrase, in plot coordinates.
Side note: I'd recommend using `np.arctan2(bz[i], bx[i])` instead of  `np.arctan(bz[i] / bx[i])` to correctly handle angles beyond <-90,90> degrees.

However, you invert the x-axis with `axs.set_xlim(1, -5)`. This will make the two quiver plots behave differently. If you check the docs: `Note: inverting a data axis will correspondingly invert the arrows only with angles='xy'.`

To circumvent that for now, you can flip the angles in the second quiver plot:

```
for i in range(len(bx)):
   b_angles1.append(np.arctan(bz[i]/bx[i]))
   b_deg_xz = 180 - np.degrees(b_angles1)
```

Which produces:

[image]

This looks okay, but I can see some red underneath the blue arrows, so it's not a perfect match. If we adjust the limits to look closer...

```
axs.set_ylim(-2, 0)
axs.set_xlim(-3, -4)
```

[image]

The key issue is the difference between data coordinates and plot coordinates. Your red quivers defined with data coordinates will be correct (true to the data) and change depending on the figsize, limits, or aspect ratio you select. When you plot your blue quivers with angles instead of data coordinates, they are defined as that point and that angle on top of the plot. They will not change with the data coordinates.

Solution: set the aspect ratio to equal (or don't mix different types in the same plot):

```
for i in range(len(bx)):
   b_angles1.append(np.arctan(bz[i]/bx[i]))
   b_deg_xz = 180-np.degrees(b_angles1)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.quiver(x_pos, z_pos, bx, bz, angles='xy', color='red')
axs.quiver(x_pos, z_pos, bx, bz, angles=b_deg_xz, color='blue')
axs.set_ylim(-2, 2)
axs.set_xlim(1, -5)
axs.set_aspect('equal')
axs.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

[image]